# Fetching data and using the state hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am trying to fetch data from an api and have that data used as state with the `useState` hook.

```
fetch('https://blockchain.info/ticker') // Call the fetch function passing the url of the API as a parameter
  .then((resp) => resp.json()) // Transform the data into json
.then(function(resp) {
    setData({data: resp.json()})
    console.log(data)
```

When I run the following I get this error `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): resp.json is not a function` I am guessing I am not fetching the data correctly, as it has been a long time since I've done this.

I tried the following
`setData({data: resp})` And it crashed my browser.

 I know I am making a simple rookie mistake somewhere, so any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You already converted it to JSON in the first `.then` callback. Now its just JSON, all you need to do is use it. As far as crashing your browser, that is the problem you need to fix. What causes the crash? Where do you make this fetch call?

Comment: Your username

Comment: I made the fetch call under the function() before the return statement. Here is the full page. 
https://github.com/Imstupidpleasehelp/bitcoinTracker/blob/main/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found some issues on your github code. Please try below.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Bitcoin = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://blockchain.info/ticker') // Call the fetch function passing the url of the API as a parameter
      .then((resp) => resp.json()) // Transform the data into json
      .then((resp) => {
        console.log(resp);
        setData(resp);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header"></header>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Bitcoin;
```

Comment: Thank you. I had only done this with class components beforehand. 1 small question though, I am getting the following error ```Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch``` Is that a problem with the api? or on my end?

Comment: I could run it on codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-bash-s8xur?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

`fetch('https://blockchain.info/ticker').then(resp => {resp.json() setData(resp)}).catch(err=> console.log(err)));`
Use async await. It is shorter and it is not confusing too. In that code you don't need to chain another .then. You got the response next step is to just set the data to your hook function Like this